# Terminator weird colors particularly in manpages

Tags: command-line, 16.04, manpage, terminator

I am using the terminal emulator Terminator for quite some time(first on Ubuntu 14.04 then on Ubuntu 16.04) and I noticed that whenever I execute a command such as `man octave`, sometimes the blank lines in the help page are colored gray. This behavior is undesirable; how can I remedy this and what may be the cause?

[image]

**NOTE:** This happens occasionally and not always.

Comment: just go through this, hope it helps->https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xterm

Comment: what is the output of `echo $TERM`?

Comment: @muru The output is `xterm`.

Comment: @AkhilVarma I do not know exactly what keyword I should search for.  Furthermore, this happens only occasionally.